I want to generate a real time fft of vibration data from a triaxial MEMS accelerometer
I have been trying to generate a real-time FFT plot for my final year project on Condition Monitoring using a MEMS accelerometer (an MPU 6050) and an Arduino UNO. My goal is to generate a real-time FFT plot of the acceleration data obtained in the 3 axes without additional hardware (if possible). Between MATLAB and Arduino, which is the better choice to generate a real-time FFT plot?. Also, i am not very well versed with Signal Processing. However, i intend to learn Signal Processing and need guidance on it. Suggestions are welcome.

Would it be possible to make the question a bit more specific? "...which is the better choice to generate real-time FFT plot" does not have a specific answer. Are you referring to the hardware? The way of capturing the information? Communicating with MATLAB? Doing the visualisation of the FFT? Perhaps it would help if you included in your question, what sort of work you have already done on your way to implementing your final year project (?). How do you plan to solve this engineering "problem"?

I don't believe that the Arduino has any means of hooking up a display directly or the required graphics capabilities.  A spectrum analyzer is easy to do in Matlab on host computer. You just need to figure out a way to pump the data from the Arduino to the host in real time.
